# Android: How to: draw shapes and text in the still image (png file) then put into ImageView?

Tags: android, bitmapimage, android-canvas

Here's my current code:

```
public class MallMapActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String tag = "MallMapActivity";
    private ImageView iv;
    private final static String FLOOR = "F";
    private final String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appdata23";
    private final String localMapsPath = storagePath + "/localMaps";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        //iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        final LinearLayout levelLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.level_layout);
        int levelSize = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < levelSize; i++) {
            Button levelButton = new Button(this.getApplicationContext());
            if(i==0) {
                levelButton.setText(new StringBuffer((i+1)+"").append(FLOOR).append("(start)"));
            } else if (i==7) {
                levelButton.setText(new StringBuffer((i+1)+"").append(FLOOR).append("(end)"));
            } else {
                levelButton.setText(new StringBuffer((i+1)+"").append(FLOOR));
            }
            levelButton.setTag((i+1) + FLOOR);
            levelButton.setId(i);
            levelButton.setLayoutParams(
                    new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(0, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
            levelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int childCount = levelLayout.getChildCount();
                    int viewId = view.getId();

                    for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
                        Button btn = (Button)levelLayout.getChildAt(j); 
                        if(viewId == j) 
                            btn.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        else
                            btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }

                    //sample data
                    double currentPixelX = 169d;
                    double currentPixelY = 347d;
                    Log.i(tag, " currentPixelX:" + currentPixelX);
                    Log.i(tag, " currentPixelY:" + currentPixelY);

                    int circleSize = 20;
                    Paint currentPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                    currentPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    currentPaint.setAlpha(75);

                    String path = new StringBuffer(localMapsPath)
                        .append("/").append(view.getTag()).append(".png").toString();
                    File file = new File(path);
                    InputStream stream = null;
                    try {
                        stream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bitmap mapBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mapBitmap);
                    canvas.drawCircle(
                            Double.valueOf(currentPixelX).floatValue(), 
                            Double.valueOf(currentPixelY).floatValue(),
                            circleSize, currentPaint);

                    iv.setImageBitmap(mapBitmap);
                    iv.invalidate();

                }
            });

            levelLayout.addView(levelButton);
        }
        levelLayout.getChildAt(0).performClick();

    }

}
```

Here's the error content:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due
>   to uncaught exception ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.sample/com.sample.MallMapActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas**
>   **constructor** ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas**
>   **constructor** ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.graphics.Canvas.(Canvas.java:83)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   com.sample.MallMapActivity$1.onClick(MallMapActivity.java:110)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2397)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   com.sample.MallMapActivity.onCreate(MallMapActivity.java:124)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8626):     ... 11 more ERROR/SemcCheckin(8626):
>   Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/semc-checkin/crashdump ERROR/SemcCheckin(1544): Get Crash Level
>   : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump

**UPDATE:**

1. mapBitmap.isMutable() is returning false value.
2. to make it mutable i changed the code

> ```
> Bitmap mapBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
> Bitmap newMapBitmap = mapBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
> ```
>
> true);
>       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newMapBitmap);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make this change : you cant  draw on immutable bitmap instead you can create one

```
  Bitmap mapBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
//make a new mutable  bitmap 
Bitmap map = createBitmap(mapBitmap.getWidth(), mapBitmap.getHeight(),mapBitmap.getConfig());
//copy the pixel to it 
int [] allpixels = new int [ mapBitmap.getHeight()*mapBitmap.getWidth()];

mapBitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, mapBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, mapBitmap.getWidth(),mapBitmap.getHeight());

map.setPixels(allpixels, 0, mapBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, mapBitmap.getWidth(), mapBitmap.getHeight());


                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(map);
```

then start drawing

Comment: oh cool. we had the same idea. i've read android documentation that may create a copy of mutable bitmap from an original bitmap (refer to the above updated post). But I am thinking of the best approach. or maybe internally, the're doing the same thing? :)